# Search a type assigned to a 'var' in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is probably a wish, more than a question: 
In  some part of the code I have used a function like this:

```
var myProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(titulo);
```

I'd like to seach in Visual Studio any usage of the type 'PropertyInfo' (that is the internal type that takes var in this example).

Comment: You want to search for any usage of this *particular* property?  Or just `PropertyInfo` in general?  The latter is very easy to do with ReSharper "Find Usages", and I believe it's in the vanilla VS as well.

Comment: Score one for the "it pays to be explicit" crowd (chiefly: me).

Comment: The ReSharper `Find Usages` works from right clicking on the var; not sure about the standard VS Find References.

Comment: Find References will not find it. Declare a PropertyInfo on one line, infer a PropertyInfo on the next, perform a find references command from the first line on PropertyInfo, you will only find the first line.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking for a feature where Visual Studio will show you all occurrences of `var` which are inferred to be a specific type.  Unfortunately, this feature does not exist in Visual Studio.

Can you explain what you would do with this feature?  Perhaps there's a different way to get to a solution.